# Ruby net sftp upload file to relative path

Tags: ruby, net-sftp

I want to upload files to remote sftp server with relative path. For example I want to be able to upload to `sftp://myserver.com/FileStore`. I've tried using the following code but it does not work: NB: host is `myserver.com/FileStore`

```
uri = URI.parse('sftp://' + host)
Net::SFTP.start(uri.host,username,:password=>password,:port=>port) do |sftp|
                    sftp.upload(testupload.zip,"#{uri.path}/testupload.zip")
                end
```

This is the error I get:

```
Net::SFTP::StatusException open /FileStore/testupload.zip (2, "no such file")
```

Comment: are you sure that this file is in the correct place, and this is the correct path? is `testupload.zip` calling the method zip in the testupload object? maybe you need to remove the `testupload.zip` from the target patch?

Comment: Even if I remove that it still doesn't work. I think the problem is it's detecting it as full path instead of relative path from the user's home directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've being able to resolve it using the following code:

```
uri = URI.parse('sftp://' + host)
Net::SFTP.start(uri.host,username,:password=>password,:port=>port) do |sftp|
    sftp.upload(testupload.zip,"./#{uri.path}/testupload.zip")
end
```

Always assuming that the path after the server name is a relative path from logged on user's home directory.